# Firefox behaves strangely when changing an element's position (CSS left, right, top, bottom) using jQuery.animate

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, jquery-animate

Consider the following fiddle in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/rawKC/1/

Click the red rectangle and see how it moves. It disappears at once, then warbles out of nowhere somewhere at the top and comes to a stop at its proper end point. The expected behaviour (as can be seen in Chrome, for example) is to wander to its end point in a straight line, changing size as specified in the animate call.

The rectangle is absolutely positioned using the left, right, top and bottom attributes. This is also how its size is determined. Upon clicking, the wrapper's positioning attributes are changed. I have no idea why the animation doesn't work in Firefox.

I can think of a number of workarounds, but I would like to find out what's wrong with this particular use case. Does anybody have an idea?

**EDIT**

It seems like the containing element's styling is of no importance at all. Only the moving element behaves strangely. I've updated the question and fiddle accordingly.

*Code snippets for reference:*

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

    $wrapper.click(function() {
        $wrapper.animate({
            bottom: '85%',
            left: '2%',
            right: '75%',
            top: '2%'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    bottom: 35%;
    left: 18%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 18%;
    top: 35%;
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that Firefox required explicit declaration of at least two attributes when using position:absolute;. Perhaps adding a left:0 to your #content will help?

Comment: That does not seem to do anything to fix the behaviour, and also keep in mind that using top rather than bottom seems to be okay. I just found something interesting out, though, I'll update the question.

Comment: You can actually keep clicking the rectangle, it'll start a new animation each time, even though the position attributes never change again. What on earth is happening here?

Comment: Another thing: I tried the jQuery versions jsfiddle has to offer, and it is broken in all of them, but it is differently broken in version 1.7.2 and downwards. In those versions, only the height of the element is abruptly decreased, then the animation continues flawlessly. It is significantly more broken from version 1.8.3 upwards.

Comment: I can add a further wrinkle for you.  It will work in Firefox when Firebug is running.

Comment: Really? And when it is off, it does not work? What version of Firefox? For me, it is broken no matter what. Curious.

Comment: @MartinDenk Firefox 18.0.1/Firebug 1.11.1/Windows 8 Pro 64.  And yes, it gets wonky without Firebug but behaves like Chrome with Firebug on.